# npm install doesn't install my dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, vps

I have build a web app using node and angular cli. The app works fine, the problem is when I try to deploy it on the web server.
I downloaded the whole project from Github but when I run "npm install" it seems like its installing something but, when I try to do "ng build" tells me: "ng: command not found"

[Example of when I try to run ng build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4IzE.png)

Comment: you need to install angular cli.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have angular-cli installed:

Install it using:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

And try again.